# Android studio gradle build running infinitely

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I changed the compileSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion and dependencies from 26 to 27 on build.gradle file and clicked the sync button.

Here's my problem. The gradle build running never ends. I've been waiting several hours.

This problem also appears when I run project too.

What is the cause of problem?

**build.gradle(Module: app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gywjd.comprehensivedesign"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            crunchPngs false
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
            ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = false
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            crunchPngs false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
        maxProcessCount 4 // this is the default value
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation  'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

**build.gradle(Project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**VMoptions**

```
# custom Android Studio VM options, see             
https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html
-Xms3g
-Xmx7g
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1024m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

**gradle.properties**

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
org.gradle.daemon=true
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms2800m -Xmx6144m 

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

[image: gradle console]
[image]
[image: gradle setting]
[image: compiler setting]